# I have a array like this in laravel , I want to remove the array which is having total greater than 480

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'name' => 'Ashish',
      'email' => 'ashishm@gmail.com',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'date' => '2022-07-04',
      'total' => '915',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'date' => '2022-07-05',
      'total' => 0,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'date' => '2022-07-06',
      'total' => '360',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an array that contains 4 entries. Each of those are arrays. You want to remove the one that has `total = 915`. This would be the resulting array:

```
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'name' => 'Ashish',
      'email' => 'ashishm@gmail.com',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'date' => '2022-07-05',
      'total' => 0,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'user_code' => '073',
      'date' => '2022-07-06',
      'total' => '360',
    ),
)
```

Is this what you are looking for or are you trying to remove several entries whenever the total exceeds 480 via some sort of script or validation before it's created. If so, I need to see more code to understand where this array comes from.

----EDITED AFTER FURTHER INFO PROVIDED ------

So it sounds like you are getting two arrays from a database and then merging them. Is this what you are doing?

```
$arrayOne = array(

    0 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '073',
        'name' => 'Ashish',
        'email' => 'ashishm@gmail.com',
    ),
    1 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '078',
        'name' => 'Tyler',
        'email' => 'test@example.com',
    ),
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    0 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '073',
        'date' => '2022-07-04',
        'total' => '915',
    ),
    1 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '073',
        'date' => '2022-07-05',
        'total' => 0,
    ),
    2 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '073',
        'date' => '2022-07-06',
        'total' => '360',
    ),
    4 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '073',
        'date' => '2022-07-04',
        'total' => '805',
    ),
    5 =>
    array(
        'user_code' => '073',
        'date' => '2022-07-04',
        'total' => '10000',
    ),
);

$mergedArray = array_merge($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);
```

If so, array_filter should work. @Bruce solution was close but it was not testing the value below 480.

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($mergedArray, function ($val) {
    if (!isset($val['total'])) return true;
    if ($val['total'] < 480) return true;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, you are right I am trying to remove the  total which exceeds 480 , I am getting this data from database from last one month and I have merged two arrays and created this one  and I want that data which has total less then 480

Comment: Hey @Tyler thank you , with the help of Bruce methods you modified it is working I am trying to run this is for each loop but I can only result of first user can you help me with this part also .

Comment: Can you clarify where your `foreach` loop is running? Are you querying the db multiple times, one for each user, and then want to filter each result? If so, it may be better to adjust your db query statement. Also, would you mind marking my answer or the one you feel was most helpful as the accepted solution? Thx.

Comment: No I am querying the DB one time only , Thank you but I figured it out I have taken Index value then pushed after for each loop .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
array_filter ($test, function ($val) {
    return !isset($val['total']) || $val['total'] < 480;
})
```

Where $test contains your Array. I added the !isset($val['total']) because the first array does not have the 'total' key and I don't know if you want to keep it or not.

Comment: Hi @Bruce , thanks for you response  If I didn't add   !isset($val['total']) it breaks but it could not remove the array which has total more then 480 .

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to filter an array:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

In your controller function:

```
$filteredArray = Arr::where($myArray, function ($value, $key) {
    $total = 0;

    if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('total', $value)) {
        $total = intval($value['total']);
    }

    return ($total <= 480);
});
```

If the value of `$total` you need to filter will may change in the future and its dynamic, you can inject it in callback function:

```
$filterTotal = 480;
$filteredArray = Arr::where($myArray, function ($value, $key) use($filterTotal) {
    $total = 0;

    if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('total', $value)) {
        $total = intval($value['total']);
    }

    return ($total <= $filterTotal);

});
```

Comment: Nice to hear that. I would appreciate if you set my answer `useful`.